# Removing linux-image-5.10.0-21-amd64, linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64 packages

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

Is it safe to remove linux-image-5.10.0-21-amd64, linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64 packages?
After removing some unnecessary firefox language packs with dependencies, I was prompted to autoremove a few packages that were no longer needed: `hunspell-gl-es, hunspell-sv-se, linux-image-5.10.0-21-amd64, linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64`.

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  hunspell-gl-es hunspell-sv-se linux-image-5.10.0-21-amd64 linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 636 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 253674 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing hunspell-gl-es (1:7.1.0~rc3-3) ...
Removing hunspell-sv-se (1:7.1.0~rc3-3) ...
Removing linux-image-5.10.0-21-amd64 (5.10.162-1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-21-amd64
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-25-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-25-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-24-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-24-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-23-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-23-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-9-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
done
Removing linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64 (5.10.179-3) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-23-amd64
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-25-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-25-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-24-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-24-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-9-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
done
```

*Edit:*

current packages:

```
$ apt list -i 'linux-image*'
Listing... Done
linux-image-5.10.0-24-amd64/now 5.10.179-5 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64/oldstable-security,now 5.10.191-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.10.0-26-amd64/oldstable,now 5.10.197-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.10.0-9-amd64/now 5.10.70-1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-image-amd64/oldstable,now 5.10.197-1 amd64 [installed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That **should** be safe, apt is pretty good at keeping track of required kernels; unless you have a pretty borked apt database.

It might pay to check your currently active kernel (make sure it has a higher version number). Apt usually keeps 2 to 3 generations of kernels around and integrated into grub.

If you have `aptitude` installed a quick check would be:

```
aptitude search ~ilinux-image
```

Without `aptitude`:

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '/linux-image/ && $2=="install"'
```

Or install aptitude ;D

Comment: `bash: aptitude: command not found`

Comment: @minto see updated answer.

Comment: ... or `apt list -i 'linux-image*'`. Also check your running kernel (`uname -r`).